# Form onSubmit with SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, sweetalert

```js
function confirmdelete()
{
return swal({   title: 'Are you sure?',
   text: 'You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!',
   type: 'warning',
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
   cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
   confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
   closeOnConfirm: false },
   function() {   
    swal(     'Deleted!',
   'Your file has been deleted.',
   'success'   );
    });
}
```

```html
<form action="<?=$site_url?>admin/islemler/delete.php" method="post" class="form-inline" onsubmit="return confirmdelete()">
  <input type="button" id="<?=$calismalarimiz['id']?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs guncelle" value="Güncelle"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="sil<?=$calismalarimiz['id']?>" value="<?=$calismalarimiz['id']?>"/>
  <input type="submit" id="sil<?=$calismalarimiz['id']?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value="Sil"/>
</form>
```

if I click submit button, sweetAlert is show, but before clicking confirm or cancel button, form post delete.php

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgGKEG this